# Android event timing (Toasts and Intents)

Tags: android, android-activity, timing, toast

I'm trying to explicitly launch an intent to a new Activity, but I would like some code in the current Activity to finish executing first. I've done a bit of research, and have a couple of ideas to accomplish this but am thinking "there's gotta be an easier way to do this". Here is the relevant block of code:

```
        cpuToast(dmg);
        if (player_.getStatus() == false)
        {
            playerWon_ = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Death.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

dmg is an int. cpuToast simply makes a String to display the damage and then calls show(). getStatus() returns whether or not the player was killed. In the event that player was killed, I launch a new intent which will play an animation of the players death. Unfortunately the "Death" Activity is being launched before the Toast even becomes visible, and then it becomes visible during the Death Activity which I do not want.

Does anyone know a simple way to ensure that the Toast executes fully prior to launching the Death Activity? From what I've found it looks like I'll have to create a "Timer" object when really all I want is a simple while loop like "while(Toast.isVisable) {}" to tie up the execution for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example code for updating the UI in response to timed events can be found at http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you begin your toast, you can also post a delayed message to your current activity; the runnable of that delayed message can start the new intent.

Comment: Ah thank you, that sounds more like the solution I'm looking for. Could you possibly post some sample code?

Comment: I don't have a trimmed down example but at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html you can find the postDelayed() method. Feed it a runnable and the delay time; your runnable will execute at about that time. If you need to post the runnable from something other than your UI thread, your UI thread can create a new Handler() and pass it to the service / etc., and that non-UI thread code can use handler.postDelayed().

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a toast?

If you are up for the idea of using a custom dialog (removed title, buttons etc.) that is probably your best bet. Use a handler to dismiss the dialog after given time and start the new activity.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a Toast, but I think I need a pause before the new Activity either way. There will also be a Tween taking place, and that needs to fully execute prior to this Activity launching as well. Do you know a way to make a pause other than "Thread.Sleep()"? I tried using that method but it also paused the execution of my Animation.